# Como gerar resultados da Mega-Sena ignorando alguns números?

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo gerar alguns jogos para Mega-Sena utilizando JavaScript, de forma que eu possa ignorar uma lista de números e indicar o total de jogos a serem gerados. Sabendo que cada jogo terá 6 números, qual a melhor forma para gerar esses jogos?

```
var numeros_ignorados = [];
var quantidade_de_jogos;
// operação para gerar jogos
```

<sup>* Mega-Sena é uma modalidade de loteria onde são sorteados seis números entre 1 a 60 não sendo repetidos.</sup>

Os `numeros_ignorados` são numeros individuais que não devem aparecer em nenhuma série. Por exemplo o `13` e o `10`.

Comment: Você pode tentar alguma função como Math.random(); http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp ou alguma outra mais avançada, como rede neural, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fica uma sugestão:

```js
var numeros_ignorados = [13, 10];
var quantidade_de_jogos = 3; // pode mudar a quantidade aqui
var jogos = [];

function gerarNumero(existentes) {
    var novoNumero = parseInt(Math.random() * 59, 10) + 1;
    if (existentes.indexOf(novoNumero) != -1 || numeros_ignorados.indexOf(novoNumero) != -1) novoNumero = gerarNumero(existentes);
    return novoNumero;
}

function chaveExistente(chave) {
    var chaves = jogos.map(function (chv) {
        return chv.join();
    });
    return chaves.indexOf(chave.join()) != -1;
}

for (var i = 0; i < quantidade_de_jogos; i++) {
    var numeros = [];
    while (numeros.length < 6) {
        numeros.push(gerarNumero(numeros));
    }
    numeros = numeros.sort();
    chaveExistente(numeros) ? quantidade_de_jogos++ : jogos.push(numeros);
}
alert(JSON.stringify(jogos, null, 4));
```

Criei uma função para gerar numeros que verifica também se o numero já existe na série.
Criei uma outra função `chaveExistente()` para verificar se a chave já saiu.

Este código gera uma array de arrays. Um exemplo é:

```
[
    [14, 21, 24, 32, 44, 50],
    [16, 33, 36, 37, 4, 44],
    [11, 2, 24, 34, 4, 45]
]
```